# Efficient way to extract Array of String's From Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

Tags: swift

Is there an efficient way to get an Array containing strings of "names" from AllData below without using nested for loops? The code works I get: "Alice", "Brad Smith MD", "Dr. Quam", "Jennifer Johnson", "John Banks MD" as output but I want to do it without the nested for loops because it's not efficient big O n^2 and it's hard to read? I am using Swift 3 in Xcode 8.2

```
 var AllData:Array<Dictionary<String,String>> = []

 override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

    AllData = [["pic":"Alice.png","name":"Alice Smith","position":"Nurse"],
               ["pic":"brad.png","name":"Brad Smith MD","position":"Primary Doctor"],
               ["pic":"user.png","name":"Dr. Quam","position":"Immunologist"],
               ["pic":"jennifer.jpg","name":"Jennifer Johnson","position":"Case Manager"],
               ["pic":"user.png","name":"John Banks MD","position":"Cardiologist"]
               ]

let names = ""

for thing in AllData { //thing is pic, name, position

                    for (key, value) in thing {
                        if(key == "name"){
                            names.append(value)
                            //print(value)
                        }
                    }
                }

 print(names)
}
```

Comment: Why do you set `AllData` to a new empty array in the static initializer, only to immediately replace it with new static data in `viewDidLoad`? Just set `AllData` directly to equal that static data.

Comment: Furthermore, swift convention is for only types to be named with UpperCamelCase. All other instance and static variables should be lowerCamelCase.

Comment: "*I get the array [...] as output*" – no you don't, you get a `String` as an output, because you made `names` a `String`. Did you mean `let names = [String]()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to iterate over a set of `(key, value)` pairs in a dictionary, to compare the keys until a particular match is found, only to use the value. Just directly subscript the dictionary:

```
var names = ""
for dict in AllData { //thing is pic, name, position
    guard let name = dict["name"] else { continue }
    names.append(name)
}
print(names)
```

The functional approach is faster and much simpler:

```
let names = AllData.flatMap{ $0["name"] }.joined(separator: "")
```

Furthermore, you shouldn't use `Dictionary` for storing data with a static set of keys. You'll have much simpler, faster and more type safe code if you use structs or classes to encapsulate the data. The final result would look something like this:

```
struct Employee {
    let pic: String
    let name: String
    let position: Sting //TODO: would this be better as an enum?
}


class MyVC: UIViewController {
    //...

    let employees = [
        Employee(
            pic: "Alice.png",
            name: "Alice Smith",
            position: "Nurse"
        ),
        Employee(
            pic: "brad.png",
            name: "Brad Smith MD",
            position: "Primary Doctor"
        ),
        Employee(
            pic: "user.png",
            name: "Dr. Quam",
            position: "Immunologist"
        ),
        Employee(
            pic: "jennifer.jpg",
            name: "Jennifer Johnson",
            position: "Case Manager"
        ),
        Employee(
            pic: "user.png",
            name: "John Banks MD",
            position: "Cardiologist"
        )
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let names = employees.map{ $0.name }.joined(separator: "")

        print(names)
    }

    //...
}
```

Both the dict and struct approach are `O(employees.count)`, but the struct approach has lower overhead, less boilerplate code, and can allow you to easy deal with non-`String` employee data.

Comment: @Hamish God you're good at this. Can I hire you as my compiler?

Comment: Haha, I'd be far too lazy for that xD

Comment: @Hamish Apparently I'm too lazy to `swiftc` my own code before I post it, so maybe I have you beat there :p

Comment: @Alexander. Great Answer! How would I count duplicates for name? if (dict["name"] == "Alice Smith") { countNames += 1 }

Comment: I think if I could edit this line to filer names by occurrences of "Alice Smith" then just count names? let names = AllData.flatMap{ $0["name"] }.joined(separator: "")

Comment: @Brian Yep. Although I highly advise you to ditch this Dictionary based approach as soon as possible. It makes no sense to use dictionaries to store a fixed set of keys

Comment: so your saying use dictionaries when keys are not fixed?

Comment: @Brain Yes. For cases when you have a fixed set of keys, structs and objects offer faster, more type safe and more convenient access to the values